# How to get data from bundle of onSaveInstanceState in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to get the data from bundle of `onSaveInstanceState` of `Activity` in Android.

I am looking to get value of this attribute `curTab` which are in bundle data.

Bundle data is here :

```
Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[{android:views={16908290=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 16908294=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 16908305=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 16908306=FragmentTabHost.SavedState{426e3158 curTab=parent2}, 16908307=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 16908310=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131492923=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131492993=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131493010=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131493204=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131493205=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131493206=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131493207=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131493208=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131493209=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8, 2131493210=android.widget.ProgressBar$SavedState@426e3140, 2131493211=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@4178b1e8}, android:focusedViewId=2131493221}], android:support:fragments=android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState@426e4770}]
```

I am trying to get `curTab` like this but I am getting null.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d("Demo", outState.getString("curTab"));
}
```

### Edit

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Demo", "onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("current_tab_selected", mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  int selectedTab = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_tab_selected");
  Log.d("Demo", selectedTab + "");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        int selectedTabIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_tab_selected");
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(selectedTabIndex);
    }
}
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: try call it before `super.onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: where your set to this curTab data by using `putString("curTab","xyz");`

Comment: @TqT No it didn't work

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal I didnt set it anywhere like that but bundle contain curTab that is I want to get retrieve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not get Data in `onSaveInstanceState();`

you need to use `onRestoreInstanceState()` instead of `onSaveInstanceState();`

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  String str = savedInstanceState.getString("curTab");

}
```

Or you can also access this in Activity `onCreate()`, if `Bundle` object is contains `curTab`.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       if(savedInstanceState != null)
          String str = savedInstanceState.getString("curTab");

    }
```

Comment: wut Is it possible to call `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` in onCreate ?

Comment: In my case onRestoreInstanceState is not calling. Why it so ?

Comment: and when I am trying to get in `onCreate` then I am getting savedInstanceState is null

Comment: Can you tell me which bundle object is debug by you ? and i have edit my answer.

Comment: see I updated the question, in my case it is already calling onSaveInstanceState then onDestroy then onCreate and then `onCreate` it is giving savedBundeInstanceState to null

Comment: Please put  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); as last line in onSaveInstanceState() callback it will work for current_tab_selected.

Comment: Yes I tried that one but didn't work still onCreate it is giving savedBundeInstanceState to null

Comment: can you put your full activity code as it is there.

Comment: I can not because it is more than thousand lines of code

Comment: Actually somewhere I called manually `finish` that why it was not calling those methods

Comment: does system call `onRestoreInstanceState` when system kill the activity right ?

Comment: and if we manually destroy the activity then it does not call right ?

Comment: When we change the configuration Activity it will call onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState , not always, and when you will manually call finish it will never ever call all these method..

Comment: When we change the configuration Activity it will call onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState , not always -- on what it depends ? why not always ?

Comment: Configuration means , orientation change, Keyboard up, Sceen size chnage, etc, beacuse system need to recreate Activity, thats why its not call always.

Answer (score 2):

You save your data in `onSaveInstanceState()` and retreive the data in `onRestoreInstanceState()` Here's an example

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
  // etc.
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```

Comment: In my case `onRestoreInstanceState` is not calling. Why it so ?

Comment: and when I am trying to get in `onCreate` then I am getting savedInstanceState is null

Comment: Because your activity needs to be destroyed before it's called. Just change your phone's orientation and both the methods will be called.

Comment: but it is already calling `onSaveInstanceState` then `onDestroy` then `onCreate`

Comment: @Williams Then after on `create()` it will automatically call `onRestoreInstanceState()`. Have a look at this link : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: I debug the program but it is not calling `onRestoreInstanceState()`

Comment: @Williams Have a look at the link that I've provided

Comment: so does it return the bundle saved instance state when system kill the activity only right ?

Answer (score 0):

public String strfoo="";

```
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        //comment this line you only fatch values from savedInstanceState


        String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("foo");

        Log.i("debug", "saved data: " + myString);

        // savedInstanceState.putString("foo", "bar");
        strfoo="bar"; set value here
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("foo");
      Log.i("debug", "saved data: " + myString);
    }

  @Override

  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     savedInstanceState.putString("foo", strfoo);
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

   }
```