# How can I store Arraylists in class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, save, onsaveinstancestate

I have a class `data`, where I store my user data.

```
public class deck {
    public static ArrayList deck = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList cardchosen = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList deck1Image = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList deck2Image = new ArrayList();
}
```

How can I save the state of those Arrays in onSaveInstanceState?
Do I have to use something different?

Comment: What is the type of ArrayList() for deck, cardchosen, deck1Image, deck2Image?

Comment: It´s all Integer ArrayList

Comment: I already tried with outstate.getIntegerArraylist but it gets red underline...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier would be to implement Serializable interface in your data class

```
public class Deck implements Serializable {

    public static ArrayList deck = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList cardchosen = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList deck1Image = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList deck2Image = new ArrayList();
}
```

and then set bundle like that in onSaveInstanceState

kotlin

```
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
        val deck = Deck()
        outState.putSerializable("mydeck", deck)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
    }
```

Java

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   outState.putSerializable("mydeck", deck);
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the onSaveInstanceState? In MainActivity? Because class `deck` doesn't have OnCreate so there's nothing to overrider...

Comment: Yes, In your activity

Comment: Unfortunately need in java

Comment: Thanks! But how can I restore that data after reopening the app? Also in MainActivity? And if so, what's the best way to get my saved data back in my deck class?

Comment: @gipi Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24075364/11538132

Answer (score 1):

You need to implicitly declare the type of ArrayList:

```
public class deck {
    public static ArrayList deck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList cardchosen = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList deck1Image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList deck2Image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

The compiler has no idea otherwise when you're trying to do:

```
ArrayList myArrayList = outstate.getIntegerArrayList("My Key")
```